# Macro (advancedfilter) is also triggered when inserting rows

Tags: excel, vba, advanced-filter

I found this amazing VBA code that automatically filters when a specific cell range changes (e.g., 1,2,3,4). However, whenever I insert a row, it automatically triggers the macro and filters it because the new row has zero value. Unfortunately I have very limited knowledge and unsure how to modify the macro so that it doesn't automatically execute when I add a row. Any help would be greatly appreciated! See below on the code used:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Range("e10:e80").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range _
("f6:e7"), Unique:=False
End Sub
```

I tried adding the following code to the end, but it didn't seem to work?

```
application.enableevents = true
```

Comment: Sorry, I just figured out a way to do this by adding an additional code:

If Target.Columns.Count < Me.Columns.Count Then

The one problem I have now is the macro runs whenever I add change anything in the new row.

Comment: All changes trigger Change event. You need to add another `If` condtion. How to determine if the change occurred in a newly added row?

Comment: @Simon Further to my answer below, I highly recommend checking out [VBA Advanced Filter - The FASTEST way to Copy and Filter Data](https://youtu.be/0YNhxVu2a5s?si=MY_NQFfLrv5toIv5) on Excel Macro Mastery's YouTube channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Stop macro if more than once cell was changed
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

'Apply advanced filter if the criteria range was changed
    Dim rgCriteria As Range
    Set rgCriteria = Me.Range("E6:F7")
    If Not Intersect(Target, rgCriteria) Is Nothing Then
        Me.Range("E10:E80").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=rgCriteria
    End If

End Sub
```

I also recommend looking into the `Range.CurrentRegion` method for identifying the entire data range when new records are added, as well as the entire criteria range if the number of criteria changes. For example: `Range("E10").CurrentRegion` and `Range("E6").CurrentRegion`. **Note:** with this method, the data range and criteria range must be separated by at least one blank row or column.